# Spring batch job wrong execution order

Tags: spring-batch

I have the following configuration for a job:

```java
            Step stepA = stepBuilderFactory.get(StepName.STEP_A)
                .tasklet(tasklet1)
                .listener(stepListener)
                .build();
    
            Step stepB = stepBuilderFactory.get(StepName.STEP_B)
                .tasklet(tasklet1)
                .listener(stepListener)
                .build();
    
            Step stepC = stepBuilderFactory.get(StepName.STEP_C)
                .tasklet(tasklet1)
                .listener(stepListener)
                .build();
    
            Step stepD = stepBuilderFactory.get(StepName.STEP_D)
                .tasklet(tasklet2)
                .listener(stepListener)
                .build();
    
            Flow flow = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("flow1")
                .start(stepA).on(Constant.COMPLETED).to(stepB)
                .from(stepA).on(Constant.FAILED).fail()
                .next(stepB).on(Constant.COMPLETED).to(stepC)
                .from(stepB).on(Constant.FAILED).fail()
                .next(stepC).on(Constant.COMPLETED).to(decider)
                .from(stepC).on(Constant.FAILED).fail()
                .next(decider).on(Constant.CONTINUE).to(stepD)
                .from(decider).on(Constant.COMPLETED).end()
                .from(decider).on("*").fail()
                .next(stepD).on(Constant.COMPLETED).to(stepA)
                .from(stepD).on(Constant.FAILED).fail()
                .build();
    
            return jobBuilderFactory.get(JobName.JOB_A)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(jobExecutionListener)
                .start(flow)
                .end()
                .build();
```

I started the job, but it failed. After that I fixed the issue manually and ran it again with the same parameters.

1st run:

```
stepA -> stepB -> stepC -> decider(CONTINUE) -> stepD (FAILED)
```

2nd run:

```
decider(CONTINUE) -> stepD (COMPLETED) -> decider(CONTINUE) -> stepD (FAILED)
```

I don't understand what happened here on the second run.
As I understand it correctly, it should run like this:

```
stepD (COMPLETED) -> stepA -> stepB -> stepC -> decider(CONTINUE) -> stepD -> stepA -> ...
```

Comment: Not sure why it is behaving like that. Can you try to change all calls to `.next` to `.from` and check if you get what you expect?

Comment: It doesn't work, however if I add the .allowStartIfComplete(true) to all steps, I have the following:
1st run: stepA -> stepB -> stepC -> decider(CONTINUE) -> stepD (FAILED)
2nd run (after fix): 
stepA -> stepB -> stepC -> decider(CONTINUE) -> stepD (COMPLETED) -> stepA -> stepB -> stepC -> decider(COMPLETED) -> end

Comment: But how can I achieve to start from the Failed step, and continue the iteration from that point.

Comment: By the way stepA, stepB and stepC can run multiple times within an iteration (RepetStatus.CONTINUABLE, RepeatStatus.FINISHED).

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, without a [minimal complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example that reproduces the issue that I can run/debug, I cannot see what could be wrong. So please share a complete example to be able to help you in an efficient way.